# Prove: $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to self-learn some number theory. Currently, I'm trying to prove the following:

$$(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$$

However, I'm a bit stumped on this one. Honestly, I'm not sure where's a good place to start.

Comment: If $n$ is composite, in general it can be expressed as the product of two factors smaller than $n-1$. Since each of those factors divide $(n-1)!$, $(n-1)! \equiv 0 \bmod n$. This is only not the case when $n$ is prime.

Comment: $n=4$ is somewhat exceptional

Comment: @KeithBackman your claim is correct, however when $n = p^2$ your argument needs some refinement since the factors are not distinct. Fortunately when $p \geq 3$ we have $2p < p^2$ so $2p^2$ divides $(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 3):

This is false for general $n$.  For example, $5!=120\equiv 0\pmod 6$, not $-1$.  In fact, $(n-1)!\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for all composite $n\geq 6$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true for $n=4$. It is true iff $n$ is prime ([Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem)). The proofs in Wikipedia are not completely elementary (use fields and Lagrange's theorem, Fermat's little theorem of Sylow theorem). Here is an elementary proof I learned in the middle school.

If $n$ is not prime then it is divisible by a prime $p<n$. Then $(n-1)!\equiv 0 (\mod p)$, hence cannot be $\equiv -1 (\mod n)$.

Suppose now that $n$ is prime. Then every number $0<k<n$ is relatively prime with $n$. Therefore there exist integers $u,v$ such that $uk+vp=1$ or $uk\equiv 1 (\mod n)$. Moreover we can replace $u$ by $u\pm pl$ for a suitable $l$ and assume $0<u=u_k<n$.

If $u_k=k$ then $k^2\equiv 1 (\mod n)$, so $(k-1)(k+1)\equiv 0 (\mod n)$. This can happen only if $k=1$ or $n-1$ (recall that $n$ is prime). Thus with every $k\ne 1, n-1$ we associate $1<u_k<n-1$ (clearly $u_k$ satisfies this) such that $ku_k\equiv 1 (\mod n)$. But then

$$(n-1)!=1(n-1)(2u_2)...(ku_k)...\equiv 1(-1)*1 =-1 (\mod n).$$